# How to open the MdSidenav from a children component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm using the **MdSidenav** component from **angular-material2** library and I want to open the **MdSidenav** from another component. So I'd like to use the functions of the local variable **#sidenav** (that is in the parent component) from another component (that is the children).

Parent component:
***src/app/app.component.html***

```
<md-sidenav-container>
 <md-sidenav #sidenav>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
 </md-sidenav>

 <div class="my-content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

Child component: ***src/app/menu/menu.component.html***

```
<div class="menu">
 <button (click)="sidenav.open()"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the child component in the router outlet?

Comment: Yes, it is. I suppose I have to use a service right?

Comment: Yup. In that case you need a service.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same similar situation. You can do this:

```
<md-sidenav-container>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav>
     <h1>Hello</h1>
  </md-sidenav>

  <menu [nav]="sidenav"></menu>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

And then in the menu component:

```
@Input() nav;

openSideNav(){
   this.nav.open();
}
```